# How necessary is a rotating shutter?

Tags: projection, display-technology

In [this explanation](https://ssec.si.edu/stemvisions-blog/what-physics-behind-watching-movie), a rotating shutter is shown and used to show each frame of a film three times. It's not exactly explained how this is accomplished with the film in motion and in place (is each frame in triplicate on the roll?), but what does it look like without the shutter? Does the film appear to fall through the frame from the perspective of the viewer? The [wagon-wheel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect) can (if I'm not mistaken) be observed under continuous light by the naked eye, so one might expect the continuously illuminated frames to be discernible under some conditions.

Comment: I've no clue about the shutter, but you cannot see the wagon-wheel effect under true continuous light, only if it's not truly continuous because of the AC frequency. This why machine shops with fast-spinning lathes, drills, grinders etc must have true continuous lighting - your life may depend on it.

Comment: This is relevant; Wikipedia has a lot of related articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movie_projector#Shutter

Comment: Can (one of) the close-voters please comment on their motivation? I don't see a problem with this question at all, but it's about to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Each frame is held in place for 1/24th of a second. The rotating shutter is there to prevent the blur that occurs when the film is advanced.

This video explains it all very well,  and shows what happens when there is no shutter (you are likely to see each frame as a vertical blur as the film is advanced). It also explains the reason why more modern projectors have the shutter rotate at three times the speed (or, rather,  has the blades) - to remove the noticeable flicker between light and dark as the shutter rotates.